# How to normalize image in openCV?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I am totally new in openCV and stuck at one point.

I have a grey scale image but I need to normalize this image. For example: I have a **cv::mat** image which may have a matrix containing some values and each index. As I have gray image it may contain only 1 value per index. Now I need to divide each value by 255.

Is there any method or facility available in openCV in C++?
For this scenario, I believe the method I want to use is called normalization in openCV?

```
cv::Mat originalMat = [OSInference cvMatFromUIImage:imgBeforeProccessing];
cv::Mat img2;

cv::cvtColor(originalMat, img2,CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::resize(img2, img2, cv::Size(128, 128), 0, 0, CV_INTER_CUBIC);
cv::Mat img3;
```

Now how to normalise (this means to divide each value in the matrix by 255)??

I am converting the mat image to an iOS image as follows:

```
+ (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    }else{
        colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Create CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols, cvMat.rows, 8, 8 * cvMat.elemSize(), cvMat.step[0], colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // get uiimage from cgimage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

    return finalImage;
}
```

Comment: look at [THIS](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mean#normalize)

Comment: Normalization means **min** -> 0 and **max** -> 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenCV has a function does exactly what you want. It's called [`convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto).

```
cv::Mat img3;
img2.convertTo(img3, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255, 0);
```

Comment: if I use my grey image converting to somewhat colour image (yellowish) is this possible?

Comment: @sss I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: As i am converting colour image to grey first then applying convertTo method....but after this my image turns yellowish ...as per my consideration grey image should remain grey even after convertTo method

Comment: @sss how do you display the converted image? resulting values are in range <0, 1> and [`cv::imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) should display it the same as before conversion

Comment: Please find my updated question..i am just calling method to convert image to IOS UIImage .  like this     img2.convertTo(img3, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255, 0);
    
    processedImageForModel = [OSInference UIImageFromCVMat:img3];

Comment: UIImageFromCVMat . is my custom method which I write in question

Comment: The answer is correct. I _think_ that the issue is that [UIImageFromCVMat](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html) handles only `CV_8U` images, while this is `CV_32F`. So, for visualization purposes, the image should be of type `CV_8U` with values in `[0,255]`

Comment: should I Convert CV_8U to CV_32F in my custom method? or is there openCV method to do this?

Comment: The easiest way is to pass to `UIImageFromCVMat` matrices of the correct type. So you can do: `Mat matToShow; img3.convertTo(matToShow, CV_8U, 255);` However, this is the opposite of the operation you just did. So you can visualize directly `img2`, and keep `img3` for further processing

Comment: @sss I see you use [`CGImageCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455149-cgimagecreate) function for your conversion. Read the doc for it, I think specyfing `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray` color space and 32 for `bitsPerComponent` and `bitsPerPixel` might help

Comment: @Miki is this correct what I am trying to do based on your information .         //------ Open CV preproccessing
    cv::Mat originalMat = [OSInference cvMatFromUIImage:imgBeforeProccessing];       
    cv::Mat img2;   
    
    cv::cvtColor(originalMat, img2,CV_BGR2GRAY);    
    cv::resize(img2, img2, cv::Size(128, 128), 0, 0, CV_INTER_CUBIC);    
    cv::Mat img3;    

    img2.convertTo(img3, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0, 0);    
    img3.convertTo(img3, CV_8U, 255);    
    
    processedImageForModel = [OSInference UIImageFromCVMat:img3];

Comment: Yes, but `img3` will be exactly equal to `img2`. I _think_ you can do: `cv::Mat img2; cv::cvtColor(originalMat, img2,CV_BGR2GRAY); cv::resize(img2, img2, cv::Size(128, 128), 0, 0, CV_INTER_CUBIC); cv::Mat img3; img2.convertTo(img3, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0, 0); processedImageForModel = [OSInference UIImageFromCVMat:img2];` and keep img3 for further processing.

Comment: However isn't clear why you need to scale by 1/255 at all ;)

Comment: I don't have further processing just needed iOS image from that cvmat which i am passing to UIImageFromCVMat method

Comment: Then just `cv::Mat img2; cv::cvtColor(originalMat, img2,CV_BGR2GRAY); processedImageForModel = [OSInference UIImageFromCVMat:img2]`

Answer (score 6):

To normalize cv::Mat you can use cv::normalize. 
I write some code to help you.

```
uchar data[] = {0, 63, 127, 255};
cv::Mat im(2, 2, CV_8UC1, data), output;
# this what you need 0 -> min value after norm
# 1 -> max value after nom
# cv::NORM_MINMAX normalize for min and max values
cv::normalize(im, output, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
std::cout 
    << im     << '\n'
    << output << '\n';
#==================================================
# output
[  0,  63;
   127, 255]
[  0,   0;
   0,   1]
```

Comment: is normalisation concept is same what i want?

Comment: @sss I believe it would behave the same as the solution in my answer, but it also has to calculate the factor (1/255) to multiply all values by itself (see [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize))

Comment: @slawekwin This is not the same as your question (and is in fact **not correct**). It's the same only if the input image happens to have both 0 and 255 values, otherwise the scaling factor is not `1/255`